# Wordpress: previous_post_link / next_post_link by alphabetical order?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, alphabetical

I'm developing a wordpress website with custom posts which are ordered alphabetically in the loop.

```
<!-- THE ARGS -->
<?php global $query_string;
$args = wp_parse_args($query_string);
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_post',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ); ?>

<!--  THE LOOP -->
<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Nothing fancy there, just a normal loop.

When I open a post, in its page I have the usual previous_post_link and next_post_link so I can navigate through posts. However, this is done by chronological order of the posts, and I wish to do so by the same alphabetical order as I used in the loop, of course. Any help on this matter would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That plugin hasn't been updated in years, not sure if it still works. In case it doesn't, [I came up with a solution][1] that can be added to your functions.php. Hope it helps!


  [1]: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166932/how-to-get-next-and-previous-post-links-alphabetically-by-title-across-post-ty/166933#166933

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like [this plug-in](http://www.ambrosite.com/plugins/next-previous-post-link-plus-for-wordpress) does what you're after, e.g.:

```
<ul class="pager">
        <?php previous_post_link_plus( array('order_by' => 'post_title') ); ?>
        <?php next_post_link_plus( array('order_by' => 'post_title') ); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This plugin hasn't been updated in a couple of years, but it still works great!!! Someone should just test it again so it can go back to the install-able options in the wp admin. I had to re-upload it from the wp site.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by using filters in the `get_adjacent_post` function.

In your functions.php file, add:

```
function mytheme_previous_post_orderby_name($orderby){
    return "ORDER BY p.post_title DESC LIMIT 1";
}
function mytheme_previous_post_where_name(){
    global $post, $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->prepare( "WHERE p.post_title < %s AND p.post_type = %s AND ( p.post_status = 'publish' OR p.post_status = 'private' )", $post->post_title, $post->post_type );
}
function mytheme_next_post_orderby_name($orderby){
    return "ORDER BY p.post_title ASC LIMIT 1";
}
function mytheme_next_post_where_name(){
    global $post, $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->prepare( "WHERE p.post_title > %s AND p.post_type = %s AND ( p.post_status = 'publish' OR p.post_status = 'private' )", $post->post_title, $post->post_type );
}
```

Then in your single.php page add the filters before you call the previous/next posts link functions:

```
add_filter('get_previous_post_sort', 'mytheme_previous_post_orderby_name', 10, 1);
add_filter('get_next_post_sort', 'mytheme_next_post_orderby_name', 10, 1);

add_filter('get_previous_post_where', 'mytheme_previous_post_where_name', 10);
add_filter('get_next_post_where', 'mytheme_next_post_where_name', 10);

the_post_navigation();

remove_filter('get_previous_post_sort', 'mytheme_previous_post_orderby_name', 10);
remove_filter('get_next_post_sort', 'mytheme_next_post_orderby_name', 10);
remove_filter('get_previous_post_where', 'mytheme_previous_post_where_name', 10);
remove_filter('get_next_post_where', 'mytheme_next_post_where_name', 10);
```

If you want to check for your specific post_type, you can add an if around the adding filter section:

```
if($post->post_type == 'my_custom_post_type'){
    add_filter(...);
    the_post_navigation();
    remove_filter(...);
}
```

or, you can just use a post_type specific single.php file!

This worked great for me, but there may be some limitations if you are planning on combining this with posts in the same term...

Comment: Danbrellis's answer has a missing apostrophe. I can't comment as this is my first account and don't have enough rep to comment. remove_filter('get_previous_post_sort', mytheme_previous_post_orderby_name', 10); Should be `remove_filter('get_previous_post_sort', 'mytheme_previous_post_orderby_name', 10);` (however even with that fix, I can't get this working)

Comment: plumbinator- thanks for catching that. are you getting close? I'm happy to take a look if you've got some sample code.

Comment: the `OR p.post_status = 'private'` should only apply to logged in users, no?

Comment: This doesn't allow for excluded terms.